# non conforming return value for std::chrono::duration::operator%() in Microsoft C++ 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm in the process of porting some C++ code to Windows (from Linux/g++4.8.1) and I noticed that Microsoft's implementation of the duration's modulus operator is incorrect.

The simple program

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << (milliseconds(1050)%seconds(1)).count() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

when compiled with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 gives the compilation error:

```
error C2228: left of '.count' must have class/struct/union
```

The standard (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4) 
has the definition as

```
template< class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2 >
typename common_type<duration<Rep1,Period1>, duration<Rep2,Period2>>::type
constexpr operator%( const duration<Rep1,Period1>& lhs,
    const duration<Rep2,Period2>& rhs );
```

I.e. the modulus operator returns a duration of the common type.  Microsoft's implementation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874810.aspx) has the definition as

```
template<class Rep1, class Period1, class Rep2, class Period2>
constexpr typename common_type<Rep1, Rep2>::type
operator%(
  const duration<Rep1, Period1>& Left,
  const duration<Rep2, Period2>& Right);
```

This incorrectly returns the underlying duration storage type.  Is this a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes it's a bug. And it is also present in vs2013 preview. You should file a bug report at ms connect as soon as possible, so they can fix it in time for vs2013.

Comment: Ok, will do.  In the mean time is it safe if I just modify my install of VS2012's chrono header?  Its only a two line change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, [this is a bug and the fix is available in Visual Studio 2015](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/794649/non-conforming-return-value-for-std-chrono-duration-operator).**

The reason it's an implementation bug comes from dimensional analysis.

Clearly if we subtract `seconds` from `seconds` the result is `seconds`.

```
seconds = seconds - seconds
```

And if we divide `seconds` by `seconds`, the result is a scalar (a scalar has no units).

```
scalar = seconds / seconds
```

And finally one can multiply `seconds` by a scalar and get `seconds`.

```
seconds = seconds * scalar
seconds = scalar * seconds
```

In [expr.mul]/p4 the standard defines the modulus operator:

> ... if the quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result,
>   `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a` ...

Said slightly differently:

```
a % b = a - (a/b)*b
```

So a `duration % duration` has the same units as:

```
seconds - (seconds/seconds)*seconds
```

which simplifies down to just `seconds`, and not a scalar.

The same analysis explains why:

```
seconds % scalar = seconds
```